# Websphere exception "Branch target offset too large for short" when using Webservices

Tags: exception, soap, websphere

When my Websphere application tries to make a call to a webservice, I get the exception:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: com.ibm.xtq.bcel.generic.ClassGenException: Branch target offset too large for short
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
```

I read that [XL-TXE-J can be configured](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/realtime/v2r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rt.doc.20%2Fuser%2Fxml%2Fxslt_migrate.html) somehow, but I don't know if this is in correlation with my error. I also have no Idea where I should configure it.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why, but setting the `com.ibm.xml.xlxp.jaxb.opti.level` JVM property to `1` makes the issue disappear.

You can configure it on your Websphere:

*Application servers > [yourserver] > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties*

[Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/xrun_jvm.html?cp=SS7JFU_8.0.0%2F1-15-5-389)